# How do I access validation messages within functional tests in Play! framework?

Tags: playframework

I have written a functional testcase to test that the controller fails a validation and redirects for a required parameter.

But I don't know how to test this from the functional test. I would expect to be able to access the validation messages and check for the error corresponding to the missing parameter. However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to access the validation error messages within the functional test.

I can access Http.cookies but I don't want to parse the cookies manually to get access to the error messages. Is there a better way of doing this ?

```
@Test
public void testMissingFullNameSignupFails() {

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("user.email", "rahulj51@gmail.com");
    parameters.put("user.password", "secret2");
    parameters.put("user.isAdmin", "true");
    Response response = POST("/signup/signupuser", parameters); 
    assertStatus(Http.StatusCode.FOUND, response);

    //how do I access the validation error messages here ?
    //Validation.current().errorsMap() returns an empty Map
    //I can see the error messages being set in the cookies but
    //I don't want to parse the cookies myself. 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a play module to make testing play apps easier and more fluent. It's called 'Litmus' and I just implemented a simple version of what you're asking for (see https://github.com/bverbeken/litmus-samples/blob/master/test/functional/htmlAssertExample/PostFormExample.java for an example).

Litmus is not a registered module yet, but you can find the source on github and clone it from there http://github.com/bverbeken/litmus.

Cheers, 
Ben

Answer (score -1):

It is better idea to use Selenium tests in Play and with selenium u will be able to see your messages with assertTextPresent() method.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasonable to check for a validation error in a functional test.